# Enforced Secession?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find a word for this concept and not had any luck in dictionaries or on Google.

If a part of a nation or state decides to separate from the whole, it *secedes*. Is there a term for a nation or state booting part of itself out? For a (purely hypothetical) example, if Canada decided it no longer wished to govern British Columbia and rescinded its sovereignty claims, what would that be called?

I thought of *expulsion* or *renunciation* but those are more general terms.

Comment: Interesting, but no state/nation has a constitution that provides for this system. However, if anything, I think "abandon" can function, e.g. "Canada abandoned British Columbia."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a rare event.

The events in 1965 when [Singapore left Malaysia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_in_Malaysia#Separation) have been called *expulsion*, *separation* and *independence*, depending on on whose history book you read.

If you want to stress that it was involuntary, then *expulsion* looks like the best word.

Comment: I think it was an amicable divorce between the Czech republic and Slovakia.

Comment: +1 Also see: [expulsion from the EU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_from_the_European_Union#Suspension).

Comment: That's an excellent example! I didn't realize it had actually happened in the modern world. The wiki page also has a linked article that refers to Singapore's forced independence as "ejection".

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, [West Virginia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Virginia) **broke away** in turn from seceding Virginia during the Civil War, thereby "seceding from secession."

Answer (score 1):

diremption

a forced sundering.

I first came across it in a translation of Hegel. The original German is, *Entzweiung* - or, split.

From the Latin, it appears to be used transitively - thus its pertinence. The state, or the self, for Hegel, *dirempts* itself and cleaves a withered portion away.

Comment: Although this word could fit the bill, it is now rarely used and few would understand it without a glance in the dictionary.